# Joomla, front end display custom column in database

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I am having some problems figuring out how to display, on the frontend website view, a custom column I've entered in the joomla _content table.

Ex. I've entered
Address
in the MYPREFIX_content table

When trying to get the information in that column I'm using

```
<?php echo $this->item->address; ?>
```

But this returns nothing.

```
<?php echo $this->item->title; ?>
```

Works just fine to get the title for example.

I assumed that it would just be a question of adding the column in the database (since I don't need to be able to edit any of the entries in Joomla backend, they don't have to be editable in the article view on the backend. All information will be collected from outside database and entered into current one).
But I'm missing something here... Do I need to let Joomla know there is a new column named "address" somewhere?

Comment: The data is obtained by the model, so you will have either modify/extend/override the model or create a content plugin.

Comment: @MasterAM Yea, I figured that something like this was the issue... I've tried adding 'address' in public function __construct($config = array()) but no go. Does anyone know how to display a custom column in the front end? What do I need to add in the model to retrieve the data?

Comment: You can change the `getItem()` method and select that column, although this is a pretty unclean way to do so. This could break under future updates to the Joomla core. Possible alternatives to this approach are to override the model or to create an extension, such as a plugin, that will store and retrieve the information and possibly even make it searchable, use a plugin that provides extra fields to content or use a CCK.

Comment: You would be best off trying to extend what is already there with the use of an extension, not edit core files, which I assume you already know is a **no no**

Comment: @MasterAM creating an extension is far beyond my skill set, and is something I might look into later on. But for now, I just need to be able to display (on the front end) data stored in the custom made column. I have a list of specific items I need to fetch from an outside source. These will be stored in individual columns for front end display. There is no need for back end editing as all the information will come from an outside source (edited in another system. So the users will never be in joomla back end).

Comment: @Lodder Yea, I know I'm not supposed to edit core files. And I try to avoid it to a maximum extent. But I don't know how to override the model (although this article suggests it's possible http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_component_mvc_from_the_Joomla!_core) I haven't got the faintest idea where to implement it  :P  And what to ad so I can display the data in my custom column (which is in the _content table).